# How to get the domain name of client accessing spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I want to get the domain names who are accessing my application.
I tried with :getHostName(),getServerName()... All gives the the domain of the Server, not the cient, I want to get domain name of client..

Comment: why u want to know that ? Have you bind your client request through websecurityConfiguration ?

Comment: you can use `request.getHeader("User-Agent");` add `, HttpServletRequest request` in your controller method, When I send request from postman, I got `PostmanRuntime/7.3.0`, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: if you hit user from browser, `Mozilla/<version> (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X <version>) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<version> Safari/<version>`

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but I am still on the same page. I have to 2 microservices ; A and B. All the request coming to B , I want to verify that it is coming from A domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject HttpServletRequest in your controller's method and use

```
@GetMapping("/getInfo")
public void getRemoteHost(HttpServletRequest request,...) {
     System.out.println("=========> "+request.getRemoteAddr());
}
```

Comment: This is only half an answer. The OP wanted the domain so he's going to need at least an up to date IP -> subnet lookup service in addition to this.

Comment: Old question but I believe `HttpServletRequest.getHeader("host");` should do the trick.